# Do scikit-learn classifiers automatically one-hot encode?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, one-hot-encoding

I'm confused by the behavior of the fit methods for the scikit-learn classifiers. I'm preprocessing my array that identifies the classes such that they are one-hot encoded, e.g, the shape is (n_samples, n_classes).

However, when I try to use algorithms like SVC or logistic regression, I get the following error: `ValueError: bad input shape (100, 3)`.

Now in fairness, the documentation does indicate that the for `fit(X,y)`
, y should be defined as follows: `y : array-like, shape (n_samples,)`. Additionally, if I just load the Iris data set, iris.target is also an array of length n_samples.

My question is, does scikit-learn automatically one-hot encode the classes when I run an arbitrary classification algorithm? If so, it's not clear that the need to do that pre-processing step as a user has been obviated. I'm assuming that that must be the case, because my impression is that one-hot encoding yields better performance than incrementally ordering the classes. But maybe that assumption is also incorrect.